# How can I "change until end of line" in vim on a Mac?

Tags: macos, vim

I just encountered a weird error. I'm new to a MacBook but not really to vim. I installed vim via homebrew and copied my .vimrc from my arch linux machine. Everything works as I would expect but when I want to change until the end of line (ct$), I get "YR: Enter character: $"... what does that mean? Jumping to the end of line with "$" works fine, only when I want to change until the end of the line it won't work. "ct(" for example works.. any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `C` or `c$` to delete until end-of-line and enter insert mode.

`t` means "until", but `$` by itself means "*until* end-of-line" so there's no need for `t$`.

Comment: Shame on me! Thank you very much for the clarification :)